# Formula to align numbers in blocks of 128

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, arguments, alignment

I would like to know the formula to align using this pattern

```
From 2088 To 2175 = 128
From 2176 To 2263 = 256
From 2264 To 2351 = 384
From 2352 To 2439 = 512
From 2440 To 2527 = 640
From 2528 To 2615 = 768
```

Each block of `88` increases the final result in `128`, what would be the *formula to do this*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a *linear function*, in *floating point* case you can reconstruct it by two points:

```
 y = (x * 16 - 32000) / 11
```

If you want *integer* steps `128, 256, 384...` you can do it by dividing and multiplying by `128`

```
 y = (x * 16 - 32000) / 11 / 128 * 128
```

**Code:**

```
static int Compute(int x) => (x - 2000) / 88 * 128;
```

**Demo:**

```
var tests = new (int from, int to)[] {
  (2088, 2175),
  (2176, 2263),
  (2264, 2351),
  (2352, 2439),
  (2440, 2527),
  (2528, 2615),
};

string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(test => $"From {test.from} To {test.to} = [{Compute(test.from)} .. {Compute(test.to)}]")
);

Console.Write(report);
```

**Output:**

```
From 2088 To 2175 = [128 .. 128]
From 2176 To 2263 = [256 .. 256]
From 2264 To 2351 = [384 .. 384]
From 2352 To 2439 = [512 .. 512]
From 2440 To 2527 = [640 .. 640]
From 2528 To 2615 = [768 .. 768]
```